# Rails 4: How to display error message using a prop name in f.label

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Is it possible to display error message using a prop name in f.label?

I'd like to display "abc is invalid" instead of "Email is invalid", "xyz is too short (minimum is 6 charachtars)" instead of "Password is too short (minimum is 6 charachtars)".

models\user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
.
.
.
  validates :email, presence: true, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }
.
.
.
end
```

new.html.erb

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="form-space">
  <%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
    <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
    <%= render 'fields', f: f %>
    <br>
    <%= f.submit "create", class: "btn btn-warning" %>
  </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

_fields.html.erb

```
<%= f.label :email, "abc" %>
<%= f.text_field :email %>

<%= f.label :password, "xyz" %>
<%= f.password_field :password %>
```

_error_messages.html.erb

```
<% if object.errors.any? %>
  <div id="error_explanation">
    <div class="alert alert-error">
      The form contains <%= pluralize(object.errors.count, "error") %>.
    </div>
    <ul>
    <% object.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
      <li>* <%= msg %></li>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the I18n translations file (`config/locales/en.yml`) to "translate" these names. When displaying error messages, ActiveRecord will first look up the `activerecord.attributes.user.email` entry before defaulting to the field's name.

```
en:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      user:
        email: "abc"
        password: "xyz"
```